# Adding a taxonomy specific css file to certain pages

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, theming

Im building a web page with multiple sub-portals, which should all have slightly different css styles.
Is it possible to add a certain css file depending on the taxonomy of a node? With `drupal_add_css` maybe?
Im using Drupal 6.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load certain CSS files based on taxonomy, maybe you could name your files according to taxonomy vocabularies. Just build the file name based on the vocabulary of a term.

```
$file = 'mymodule_taxonomy_' . $vocabulary . '.css';
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/' . $file);
```

If you have a node object you can use `taxonomy_node_get_terms()` to get the terms for a node and use this code to load a proper CSS file.
Then, with a vocabulary named `cars` you can name a CSS file `mymodule_taxonomy_cars.css`. That file can be loaded according to a vocabulary.